# Any syntax checker for ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've spent 30 minutes to debug a piece of code.

Used $key instead of @key.

How can I check the syntax? Any tools on SFMC?

Comment: There is that free AMPScript Editor 'app' in AppExchange, but it honestly isn't that good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SublimeText3 with an Add-on of SeanJA [https://github.com/SeanJA/ampscript-st2.](https://github.com/SeanJA/ampscript-st2)

Pretty easy to setup and also highlights HTML.
Only downside is that the if fold function is not 100% correct.

I believe that this is one of the best tools.

Comment: Will test, thank you

Comment: What do you mean by the "if fold" function. Is that IIF()?

Comment: When you write code you can usually click on codeblocks to only show the first line. For example if you write a 50 line if statement and you „fold“ it it will only show one line. And then the statement that comes after the if has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Salesforce Marketing Cloud Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/fkmojdpmdmdmeohmebiejjclmegkalli) for Google Chrome, which a.o. does syntax highlighting and syntax error warning.

Comment: doesn't work in latest Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I've written a new AMPscript syntax highlighter.  It's in the Sublime Text package repository: [AMPscript Syntax Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AMPscript%20Syntax%20Highlighter).

It replaced the old SeanJ one.

The source is here: https://github.com/wvpv/ampscript-syntax-highlighter